# Can stolen supplies be used to craft reactor coolant?

Tags: fallout-4, ps4

In Fallout 4, one of the repeatable quests is to craft reactor coolant for Proctor Ingram on the Prydwen.  Because the supplies are rare, is it possible to use stolen items for crafting the coolant?

Comment: Moved from terrorism.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Crafting does not care whether the junk parts are stolen or not.